# How to using Google Flan for few-shot learning?

Tags: nlp

I'm sorry, I'm just starting to learn NLP. I am learning how to use Google Flan.

I'm not sure how to provide the few-shot example to the model and run which file to get the results.

Here is the code link:
https://github.com/google-research/FLAN

Here is the paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01652
Many thanks!